# Make 7 SQL Query Like This Into Single Query, Is It Possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 7 SQL Query to do a task like this :

```
1. UPDATE Customer SET CustomerService = 'perta' WHERE FirstName = 'john';
2. UPDATE Customer SET Flag = 1 WHERE OrderNum BETWEEN 2 AND 29;
3. UPDATE Customer SET PurchaseNum = PurchaseNum + 60 WHERE OrderNum BETWEEN 2 AND 29;
4. UPDATE Customer SET OrderNum = OrderNum + 60 WHERE OrderNum BETWEEN 2 AND 29;
5. UPDATE Customer SET PurchaseNum = PurchaseNum - 28 WHERE (PurchaseNum > 29 AND PurchaseNum <= 89) AND (Flag <> 1);
6. UPDATE Customer SET OrderNum = OrderNum - 28 WHERE (OrderNum > 29 AND OrderNum <= 89) AND (Flag <> 1);
7. UPDATE Customer SET Flag = 0 WHERE OrderNum BETWEEN 62 AND 89;
```

is it possible to 'compress' those SQL Queries into 1 Query?

because I'm afraid that user cancel the process by pressing the ESC button (after he/she press the SUBMIT button), those sequence will be broken in the middle and my table will be messy as well.

Comment: Use transactions! (and a storage engine that supports them)

Comment: Why not use transaction?

Comment: heard about Transaction? Also once the client makes a HTTP request he cant go and cut the wire that is transmitting the request...

Comment: thanks for the clue, guys... I'm still thinking now... what's the difference between starting transaction with START TRANSACTION + COMMIT and combination of autocommit = 0 + autocommit = 1? any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL then see this link it shows you how to implement transaction in MySQL.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html

Transaction helps us in many scenario and you are handling  one of them where you want to update multiple database tables.